# C# Multiple choice attempts and restart

Tags: c#, while-loop, restart

I seem to be having some trouble with my multiple choice program. I can't seem to figure out how to do attempts in a while loop. For example, I give you two attempts and lets say you got the first question wrong. Then it will give you another try at the same question. I think I need to use a while loop I just can't seem to figure out how to implement it. Also, is there A way that I can restart the program if the isn't 100?

```
string First;
        int score = 0;
        string Second;


        TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;


        Console.Write("Where is  the capital of the state of Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");

        First = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (First)

        {

            case "B":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct answer!");



                break;

            case "A":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            case "C":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            case "D":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            default:


                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct answer.");

                break;

        }
        if (First == "B")
        {
            score = score + 50;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" +  " score:" + score + "\n");
        }
        Console.Write("Where is Walt Disney World Park located in Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");

        Second = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (Second)

        {

            case "A":

                Console.Write("You entered the correct answer!");



                break;

            case "B":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            case "C":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            case "D":

                Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");

                break;

            default:


                Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct answer.");

                break;

        }
        if (Second == "A")
        {
            score = score + 50;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        }
```

Comment: Since there's only one right answer and the rest are all wrong, you can replace the `switch/case` with an `if`: `if (First == 'B') { // Right } else { // Wrong }`

Comment: Try putting each your questions (i.e. asking the question, reading the input and the switch statements) into a separate method returning a bool for correct / incorrect answer.  Call the method again if it returns false. Also, as @itsme86 stated, you don't really need a switch statement to test for all possible combinations: you're only interested if the input was correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by others, you should change the approach of your code to make it more flexible and avoid needless duplication. However, if I were to follow your structure, you could use an integer variable to store the amount of attempts left, and decrease it each time an incorrect answer is submited. Encase the code of each question in a while loop where the condition is that the number of attempts left is > 0. Example:

```
string First;
int score = 0;
int attempts = 2; //our integer variable 
string Second;
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

while (attempts > 0)
{
    //First question
    Console.WriteLine("Where is  the capital of the state of Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa"); //use WriteLine instead of Write, for console clarity
    First = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (First.ToUpper()) //accept lowercase inputs
    {
        case "B": Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct answer!"); break;
        case "A": case "C": case "D": Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer."); break; //same logic
        default: Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct answer."); break;
    }
    if (First.ToUpper() == "B")
    {
        score = score + 50;
        Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        break; //force exit loop, onto the next question
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        attempts--; //decrease number of attempts left
    }
 }
 while(attempts > 0)
 {
    //Second question
    Console.WriteLine("Where is Walt Disney World Park located in Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");
    Second = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (Second.ToUpper()) //accept lowercase inputs
    {
        case "A": Console.Write("You entered the correct answer!"); break;
        case "B": case "C": case "D": Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer."); break;
        default: Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct answer."); break;
    }
    if (Second.ToUpper() == "A")
    {
        score = score + 50;
        Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        break; //you win!
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        attempts--; //decrease number of attempts left
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually exactly how I wanted it to look! Thank-you for the advice and I really need to work on my duplication problem to make coding to easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your approach to checking for the right answer will help make what you're trying to do clearer. I would suggest making a class to hold question information:

```
class Question
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string Answer { get; private set; }

    public Question(string text, string answer)
    {
        Text = text;
        Answer = answer;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a list of questions instead of needing to create large branching structures for each one:

```
List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
questions.Add(new Question("Where is the capital of...", "B"));
questions.Add(new Question("Where is Walt Dis...", "A"));
```

Now to ask questions, you can loop through your list. It's also easy to add your second chance feature:

```
foreach (Question question in questions)
{
    bool answeredCorrectly = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)  // up to 2 chances
    {
        Console.Write(question.Text);
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == question.Answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You answered correctly!");
            answeredCorrectly = true;
            break;  // Make sure we break out of the for loop so we don't ask a second time
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That's not correct.");
        }
    }

    if (answeredCorrectly)
    {
        // Add 50 points to their score, etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write the while loop like this

```
while (score!=50) {
            // Do stuff
        }
```

Thats the program how i would write it

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string First; //You should use a char
        int score = 0;
        string Second;


        //TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;


        Console.Write("Where is  the capital of the state of Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");



        // Here is the while loop
        // While score is not 50 do stuff
        while (score!=50) {
        First = Console.ReadLine();
            score = checkanswer(First, "B", 50, score);
        }

        Console.Write("Where is Walt Disney World Park located in Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");



        while (score != 100) { Second = Console.ReadLine();
            score = checkanswer(Second, "A", 50, score);
        }
    }
    // I added this little fancy function. It makes your program more structured and a little bit smaller ;)
    static int checkanswer(string userinput, string rightanswer, int winpoints, int score){
        if (userinput==rightanswer) {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + winpoints + score + "\n");
            return winpoints + score;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
            return score;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Ask(string question, string answer, int attempts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(question);
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (input == answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            return true;
        }

         Console.WriteLine("Incorrect.");
    }

     return false;
}

static void Main()
{
    int score = 0;
    if (Ask("Where is Walt Disney World Park located in Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa", "B", 3))
    {
        score += 50;
    }
    else
    {
        score -= 50;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Score :" + score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@itsme86's answer is good if you want to do it object-oriented and such. 
But if you are just trying to learn while-loops then the following is a very simple/stupid/ugly way of achieving what you are trying to do:

```
Console.Write("Where is  the capital of the state of Florida? A.Orlando,B.Tallahassee, C. Miami, or D. Tampa");
        var first = "";
        bool answeredCorrect = false; //Track B answered.
        int attempts = 0; //Track 2 attempts.
        while (!answeredCorrect && attempts < 2)
        {
            first = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (first)
            {

                case "B":

                    Console.WriteLine("You entered the correct answer!");
                    score = score + 50;
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");

                    answeredCorrect = true;
                    break; //break and skip while because "answeredCorrect" is now true. 

                case "A":

                    Console.WriteLine("You entered the wrong answer.");
                    attempts++; //Inkrement attempts. (One more try. Or skip if attemps is 2)
                    break;

                //case C,D...

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a correct answer.");
                    attempts++; //Inkrement attempts. (One more try. Or skip if attemps is 2)
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(first != "B")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n" + " score:" + score + "\n");
        }
```

(Some at our company writes this kind of code)